# Getting unquoted variable names from a vector using rlang

Tags: r, rlang

I am building a function for which I'd like the user to be able to pass unquoted variables. Later on I'm going to need the names of those variables as strings as I prepare the output.

This is no problem if each argument carries only one variable. I can use `deparse(substitute(x))` or `rlang::as_name(rlang::enquo(x))` to get the name out (with the latter probably being the better approach). But how do I do this if I have them passing in multiple variables in one argument using `c()`?

The only way I've figured out how to do it so far, after reading a whole bunch about quosures, etc., is `names(dplyr::select(data,{{x}}))` but I can't imagine that's the proper way to do this.

```
nameprinter <- function(x, manynames, onename) {
  manynames <- names(dplyr::select(x, {{manynames}}))
  onename <- rlang::as_name(rlang::enquo(onename))

  c(manynames,onename)
}

df <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=1:10,c=1:10)

nameprinter(df,c(a,b),c)
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

What's a better approach to getting the names of the variables passed in `manynames` than I have here? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually already a function for it. We can use `vars_select`

```
tidyselect::vars_select(names(df), c(a,b), c)
# a   b   c 
#"a" "b" "c" 

tidyselect::vars_select(names(df), a, b)
#  a   b 
# "a" "b"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use base R to accomplish this:

```r
nameprinter <- function(x, manynames, onename) {
  manynames <- substitute(manynames)
  names_env <- setNames(as.list(names(x)), names(x))
  manynames_quo <- eval(manynames, names_env)

  onename <- deparse(substitute(onename))

  c(manynames_quo,onename)
}

df <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=1:10,c=1:10)

nameprinter(df,c(a,b),c)
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

This evaluates our manynames vector based on the names of the variables in our df. This should be a fair bit quicker than using `select` and then pulling out the names.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you need to work with the `rlang::enquo` function directly for this problem:

```
library("dplyr")

nameprinter <- function(x, manynames, onename) {

  select(df, !!manynames) %>% print()
  select(df, !!onename) %>% print()

  c(manynames, onename)
}

df <- tibble(a = 1:10, b = 1:10, c = 1:10)
nameprinter(df, c("a", "b"), "c")
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: My concern was that pulling out the names using `select` seemed so kludgy, that there must be a cleaner way, such as how `as_name` works with the single variable. Is `select()` the best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

I tought of an approach that is more generic and does not depend on a data frame. It uses `as_name` and applies it to the quosures using `vapply`...

```
foo <- function(.data, value_col, ...) {
  group_cols <- enquos(...)
  value_col <- enquo(value_col)
  # do stuff
  .data %>% group_by(!!!group_cols) %>% summarize_at(vars(!!value_col), mean) %>% print()
  # passed columns as a character vector
  vapply(c(group_cols, value_col), rlang::as_name, "")
}
foo(mtcars, mpg, cyl, vs)
```